# Fetching multiple joins data in Set

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to fetching album details and all images associated with that album to Set `piSet` but it is not fetching all images to set `piSet`

I want like

```
 albumname   in al object     
     ABC 
    images in piSet
               image1
               image2
               image3  
               ....
```

Data fetching code is

```
 con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
                    List<Album> aList = new ArrayList<Album>();
                    try {
                        ps = con.prepareStatement("select distinct album.*,pi.* from   "
                                + "atom as a  "
                                + "left join album as album "
                                + "on   "
                                + "a.id=album.aid "
                                + "left join post_images as pi  "
                                + "on   "
                                + "album.id=pi.album_id "
                                + "where  "
                                + "a.id=? "
                                + "and a.status=? ");
                        ps.setLong(1, aid);
                        ps.setString(2, "Active");
                        rs = ps.executeQuery();

                        while (rs.next()) {
                            Set<PostImages> piSet = new HashSet<PostImages>();
                            Album al = new Album();
                            al.setId(rs.getLong("album.id"));
                            al.setName(rs.getString("album.name"));
                            PostImages pi = new PostImages();
                            pi.setImageId(rs.getLong("pi.image_id"));
                                    pi.setLargePicPath(rs.getString("pi.large_pic_path"));

                            piSet.add(pi);
                            al.setPostImageses(piSet);
                            aList.add(al);
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException e) {}
```

How to modify above code to fetch all images to 'PiSet'.

Answer (score 2):

Assume *id* is unique in *album* table, above code can satisfy your requirement:

```
rs = ps.executeQuery();
HashMap<Long, Album> AlbumMap = new HashMap<Long, Album>();
while (rs.next()) {
    Long albumId = rs.getLong("album.id");//assume album.id is unique.
    Album al = AlbumMap.get(albumId);
    if (al == null) {
        al = new Album();
        al.setId(albumId);
        al.setName(rs.getString("album.name"));
        Set<PostImages> piSet = new HashSet<PostImages>();
        al.setPostImageses(piSet);
        aList.add(al);
        AlbumMap.put(albumId, al);
    }
    PostImages pi = new PostImages();
    pi.setImageId(rs.getLong("pi.image_id"));
            pi.setLargePicPath(rs.getString("pi.large_pic_path"));
    al.getPostImageses().add(pi);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a map from id to `Album` instances, and only create a new `Album` when there is no instance yet for the given id.

I'd also advise you to let `Album` handle the `Set` internally, and just add images to album, instead of setting the set to album.

```java
Map<Long, Album> albumMap = new HashMapMap<>();
while (rs.next()) {
    long albumId = rs.getLong("album.id");
    Album album = albumMap.get(albumId);
    if (albumId = null) {
        album = new Album();
        album.setId(albumId);
        album.setName(rs.getString("album.name"));
        albumMap.put(albumId, album);
    )
    PostImages pi = new PostImages();
    pi.setImageId(rs.getLong("pi.image_id"));
    pi.setLargePicPath(rs.getString("pi.large_pic_path"));

    // Don't handle the set yourself, let Album handle it.   
    album.addPostImage(pi);
}
aList.addAll(albumMap.values());
```

As an aside: the use of table prefixes in `ResultSet.getXXX` is not JDBC standard and is - as far as I know - MySQL specific; it will make your code less portable between different databases.